# Meta Search 3 columns as one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search

I have three columns in my table product name, product color, and product brand. The table is pretty much static, I just import the data once and it does not get modified. An example would be small car, red, motor co. I want to be able to search for and get a result for "car red".

If I use
name_or_color_or_brand_contains
I do not get any results.

Is there a way to collapse the three columns during the search or is creating a column that has the info of the three column a possible solution seeing that my data does not change that much.

Thanks!